# Why my model training automatically stopped during training?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api, mobilenet

I was trying to make a custom detector using **SSD MobileNet**. I never tried this model before for making a custom detector using TensorFlow API. I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZ7FYAMCc4M&t=242s).

I am facing a problem after the start of my model training, where the training session automatically stopped without showing any kind of error message. [My code!](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_CpWUmiT-FaZkJ5sXoX_Lt-doV8X1dfN?usp=sharing).

> **Training Log:**

Note: I didn't press ctrl+c.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/__init__.py:98: UserWarning: unable to load libtensorflow_io_plugins.so: unable to open file: libtensorflow_io_plugins.so, from paths: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/libtensorflow_io_plugins.so']
caused by: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/libtensorflow_io_plugins.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3tsl5mutexC1Ev']
  warnings.warn(f"unable to load libtensorflow_io_plugins.so: {e}")
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/__init__.py:104: UserWarning: file system plugins are not loaded: unable to open file: libtensorflow_io.so, from paths: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/libtensorflow_io.so']
caused by: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/libtensorflow_io.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK10tensorflow4data11DatasetBase8FinalizeEPNS_15OpKernelContextESt8functionIFN3tsl8StatusOrISt10unique_ptrIS1_NS5_4core15RefCountDeleterEEEEvEE']
  warnings.warn(f"file system plugins are not loaded: {e}")
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow_addons/utils/ensure_tf_install.py:53: UserWarning: Tensorflow Addons supports using Python ops for all Tensorflow versions above or equal to 2.9.0 and strictly below 2.12.0 (nightly versions are not supported). 
 The versions of TensorFlow you are currently using is 2.8.0 and is not supported. 
Some things might work, some things might not.
If you were to encounter a bug, do not file an issue.
If you want to make sure you're using a tested and supported configuration, either change the TensorFlow version or the TensorFlow Addons's version. 
You can find the compatibility matrix in TensorFlow Addon's readme:
https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  warnings.warn(
2023-03-31 18:36:31.484647: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:39] Overriding allow_growth setting because the TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH environment variable is set. Original config value was 0.
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
I0331 18:36:31.520529 140062219949888 mirrored_strategy.py:374] Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting train_steps: 30000
I0331 18:36:31.525732 140062219949888 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting train_steps: 30000
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
I0331 18:36:31.525894 140062219949888 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py:563: StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
rename to distribute_datasets_from_function
W0331 18:36:31.564539 140062219949888 deprecation.py:337] From /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py:563: StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
rename to distribute_datasets_from_function
INFO:tensorflow:Reading unweighted datasets: ['/content/train.tfrecord']
I0331 18:36:31.579699 140062219949888 dataset_builder.py:162] Reading unweighted datasets: ['/content/train.tfrecord']
INFO:tensorflow:Reading record datasets for input file: ['/content/train.tfrecord']
I0331 18:36:31.579885 140062219949888 dataset_builder.py:79] Reading record datasets for input file: ['/content/train.tfrecord']
INFO:tensorflow:Number of filenames to read: 1
I0331 18:36:31.579969 140062219949888 dataset_builder.py:80] Number of filenames to read: 1
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
W0331 18:36:31.580035 140062219949888 dataset_builder.py:86] num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:100: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.deterministic`.
W0331 18:36:31.586066 140062219949888 deprecation.py:337] From /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:100: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.deterministic`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:235: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
W0331 18:36:31.623633 140062219949888 deprecation.py:337] From /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:235: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1082: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
W0331 18:36:40.595004 140062219949888 deprecation.py:337] From /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1082: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1082: sample_distorted_bounding_box (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
`seed2` arg is deprecated.Use sample_distorted_bounding_box_v2 instead.
W0331 18:36:44.812320 140062219949888 deprecation.py:337] From /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1082: sample_distorted_bounding_box (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
`seed2` arg is deprecated.Use sample_distorted_bounding_box_v2 instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1082: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
W0331 18:36:47.381695 140062219949888 deprecation.py:337] From /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1082: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/backend.py:450: UserWarning: `tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase` is deprecated and will be removed after 2020-10-11. To update it, simply pass a True/False value to the `training` argument of the `__call__` method of your layer or model.
  warnings.warn('`tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase` is deprecated and '
I0331 18:37:46.895673 140056366921472 api.py:441] feature_map_spatial_dims: [(19, 19), (10, 10), (5, 5), (3, 3), (2, 2), (1, 1)]
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
I0331 18:37:51.184225 140056366921472 convolutional_keras_box_predictor.py:152] depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
I0331 18:37:51.184609 140056366921472 convolutional_keras_box_predictor.py:152] depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
I0331 18:37:51.184831 140056366921472 convolutional_keras_box_predictor.py:152] depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
I0331 18:37:51.184998 140056366921472 convolutional_keras_box_predictor.py:152] depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
I0331 18:37:51.185159 140056366921472 convolutional_keras_box_predictor.py:152] depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
I0331 18:37:51.185317 140056366921472 convolutional_keras_box_predictor.py:152] depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
I0331 18:38:00.069848 140056366921472 api.py:441] feature_map_spatial_dims: [(19, 19), (10, 10), (5, 5), (3, 3), (2, 2), (1, 1)]
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0331 18:38:18.716928 140062219949888 cross_device_ops.py:616] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0331 18:38:18.718183 140062219949888 cross_device_ops.py:616] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0331 18:38:18.720197 140062219949888 cross_device_ops.py:616] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0331 18:38:18.721046 140062219949888 cross_device_ops.py:616] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0331 18:38:18.723185 140062219949888 cross_device_ops.py:616] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0331 18:38:18.724060 140062219949888 cross_device_ops.py:616] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0331 18:38:18.725992 140062219949888 cross_device_ops.py:616] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0331 18:38:18.727001 140062219949888 cross_device_ops.py:616] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0331 18:38:18.728958 140062219949888 cross_device_ops.py:616] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
I0331 18:38:18.729797 140062219949888 cross_device_ops.py:616] Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py:616: calling map_fn_v2 (from tensorflow.python.ops.map_fn) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use fn_output_signature instead
W0331 18:38:19.432796 140056383706880 deprecation.py:541] From /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py:616: calling map_fn_v2 (from tensorflow.python.ops.map_fn) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use fn_output_signature instead
I0331 18:38:20.334592 140056383706880 api.py:441] feature_map_spatial_dims: [(19, 19), (10, 10), (5, 5), (3, 3), (2, 2), (1, 1)]
I0331 18:38:29.071922 140056383706880 api.py:441] feature_map_spatial_dims: [(19, 19), (10, 10), (5, 5), (3, 3), (2, 2), (1, 1)]
I0331 18:38:38.090057 140056383706880 api.py:441] feature_map_spatial_dims: [(19, 19), (10, 10), (5, 5), (3, 3), (2, 2), (1, 1)]
I0331 18:38:46.651757 140056383706880 api.py:441] feature_map_spatial_dims: [(19, 19), (10, 10), (5, 5), (3, 3), (2, 2), (1, 1)]
^C
```

Comment: The above error log indicates that there is a version mismatch issue with the installed `tensorflow` and `tensorflow_addons`.  This model installs `tensorflow_addons 0.19.0` which is only supported with `Tensorflow >= 2.9` as mentioned in this [compatibility matrix](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons#python-op-compatility). Could you please try again by installing `tensorflow_addons==0.18.0` for installed `TensorFlow version 2.8`.

Comment: okk. Let me try @TFer2

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're consuming all your GPU resources (if you're training on a GPU). For example, if you're using a Google Colab notebook, it automatically attempts to stop the cell execution when you exceed 95% of the GPU power to prevent GPU overload.

Solution: Reduce the batch size (down to 32, 16, or maybe even 8?) until the training continues.

Answer (score 0):

I had to decrease batch size to 2. I had same issue on 16 and 8 batch sizes. It must work.

Comment: !!!!!!!For those whose training not working, you probably must to restart runtime session.!!!!!
Also second time when I had this issue, even after decrreasing batch size into 2, I had to restart runtime session on google colab. Didnt understand why I need to restart but it worked